# Mulit image upload on PHP, Notice: Undefined offset: iwhen $_FILES

Tags: php, image-uploading

When I try to upload multiple image upload on PHP, it got error that 'Notice: Undefined offset: 6 when $_FILES' and the offset number is too many loop.
Here code HTML

```
<input type="file" name="imagetest[]"><br>
<input type="file" name="imagetest[]"><br
<input type="file" name="imagetest[]"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
```

and PHP code

```
for($i=0;count($_FILES['imagetest']['tmp_name']);$i++){
   echo (($_FILES['imagetest']['tmp_name'][$i]));
 }
```

Please help me, I am younger with PHP language

Comment: stop use php use nodejs instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your `for loop` you should edit the `second expression`.

> If it evaluates to TRUE, the loop continues and the nested
>   statement(s) are executed. If it evaluates to FALSE, the execution of
>   the loop ends.

```
for($i = 0;$i < count($_FILES['imagetest']['tmp_name']);$i++){
   echo $_FILES['imagetest']['tmp_name'][$i];
}
```

Comment: Nope. In the for loop edit the second expression. $i < count($_FILES['imagetest']['tmp_name'])